# When can I safely inherit from a base class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

So the basic rule that I find everywhere is that to inherit from a base class, the base class must have a virtual destructor so that the following works:

```
Base *base = new Inherited();
delete base;
```

However I am certain I have seen at least one other possibility that allows safe inheritance. However I can't find it anywhere and I feel like I am going mad trying to find it. I thought the other option might have been that the base class had a trivial destructor, but according to [Non-virtual trivial destructor + Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970523/non-virtual-trivial-destructor-inheritance), this isn't the case. Even though there wouldn't be a memory leak for this case, it appears this is still undefined behaviour.

Does anyone else know what the other case is or can you definitively tell me that I dreamt it?

Comment: well, if you don't add additional fields in the inherited class then this should be safe. oh, and also if you don't add virtual methods when base class doesn't have them.

Comment: If you just don't delete the derived class through a pointer to base, there is no problem.

Comment: If you want these two lines of code to be valid, you must have a virtual destructor in `Base`, period. If you don't, there are some options.

Comment: @BoPersson note that `shared_ptr<B>` can be used to achieve the same effect in a correct manner

Comment: @Grozz: Undefined behaviour is hardly "safe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other case I've seen mentioned is making the base-class **destructor** `protected`. That way, you prevent deletion through a base class.

This is actually item 50 in the book C++ Coding Standards by Herb Sutter et al: "Make base class destructors public and virtual or protected and non-virtual", so it is quite likely that you have heard of it before.

Comment: This is the other safe option I was looking for, well done for noting I said "safely". When I first found it I didn't understand it, which is why I didn't remember it. But as you say it means only derived classes can delete the base class avoiding the possible problem. It also mean only derived classes or internal functions can construct the base too.

Answer (score 3):

I guess an example can be the one that involves `shared_ptr`s, for it is good to show both the sides of the issue.

Suppose you have a class `B` with a trivial non virtual destructor and a derived class `D` with its own complex one.

Let's define the following function somewhere:

```
shared_ptr<B> factory () {
    // some complex rules at the very end of which you decide to instantiate class D
    return make_shared<D>();
}
```

In that case you are dealing with all the interesting features due to the polymorphism, but the pointer you are working with has inherited the `deleter` from the one constructed with type `D`.

Even though, thanks to the type erasure, the type is buried somewhere and everything works fine, the actual invoked destructor is the one of `D`, so everything should work fine also from that point of view, even though the destructor of `B` was not `virtual`.

Instead, if you define the above factory as:

```
B* factory () {
    return new D{};
}
```

The called destructor (well, supposing that someone will delete it) will be the one of `B`, that is not what you want.

That said, defining as `virtual` the destructor of a class that is meant to be inherited from is a good practice, otherwise put a `final` in the class definition and stop there the hierarchy.

There also a lot of other examples, this is not the only case *where* it works, but it can help to explain *why* it works.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps when the inheritance is private. In such a case, the user can't convert `Derived*` to `Base*` so there is no chance of trying to delete the derived class through the base class pointer. Of course, you still have to watch that you don't do this anywhere within your implementation of `Derived`.

Comment: There's a loophole. It's very unlikely to happen in real code, but still: a C-style cast *can* legally achieve the conversion to `Base*` and then invoke undefined behaviour via the `delete`. Shortest example I could come up with: `class Base {}; class Derived : Base {}; int main() { Base* b = (Base*)(new Derived); delete b; }` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899978/a-conversion-that-c-style-cast-can-handle-but-c-casts-cannot/33900968#33900968 for the special C-style cast rule.

Answer (score 2):

My take on this is pragmatic rather than anything to do with what is or isn't allowed by the standards.

So, *pragmatically*, if a class doesn't have a virtual destructor - even an empty one - then my default assumption is that it *hasn't been designed to be used as a base class*. This may have more implications than just destruction and in more cases than not, just opens a can of worms for you to fall in later.

If you want or need to use functionality from a class without a virtual destructor, it would be safer to use composition rather than inheritance. In fact, that's the preferred route anyway.

Comment: You should mention that your take on this is violated by some C++ standard classes, e.g. `std::iterator` or `std::stack`. Your guideline is good enough in most situations but is not as universal as you seem to imply.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Well, you've just mentioned that ;-) As I said above, this is pragmatism and is based on experience. I acknowledge that I err on the side of caution, which has been a useful tenet over 38 years of software development!

Comment: @RogerRowlan Actually the answer by Itjax gives another safe case, which is the case I was looking for.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, I'd be interested to know how std::iterator and std::stack deviate and how they avoid undefined behaviour - maybe just by being careful about destruction? Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: @PhilRosenberg: `std::iterator` and `std::stack` do not have a virtual destructor but are designed to be (possible) base classes. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator: *"(...) the base class provided to simplify definitions of the required types for iterators."* As for `std::stack`, it has a protected `c` member, allowing subclasses access to the wrapped container. Not terribly common use cases, but still, those are standard classes.

Comment: @PhilRosenberg: Re "how they avoid undefined behaviour". They don't. **You** have to avoid it by not attempting a polymorphic `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always inherit from a class. There are rules to obey though, e.g. without a virtual destructor you can't invoke the destructor polymorphically. In order to avoid this, you could e.g. use private derivation for baseclasses that were not intended as baseclasses, like e.g. the containers from the STL.

Comment: I agree, you can always inherit; but, it is your responsibility is for the resulting class and making sure it is safe.  The need of a polymorphic destructor is only necessarily if the derived class does something critical in its destructor (like freeing a dynamic resource).  There are ways around that too such as using containment since the destructor of members will always be called even without a polymorphic destructor.

Comment: "You can always inherit from a class" - unless it's marked `final`

Comment: Wrong language, @M.M, ;)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm talking about C++ (11 and later)

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're right with that statement, @markshancock, I could also imagine that invoking the wrong destructor causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, as long as you delete the class through it's own destructor - in other words you do

```
Inherited *ip = new Inherited();
Base *p = ip; 
... 
delete ip;
```

you'll be fine. There are several different ways to do that, but you have to be quite careful to ensure that is the case.

However, having an empty destructor in the baseclass [and your inherited type is immediately inheriting] only works as long as it is TRULY empty, and not just that you have an `{ }` for the body of the destructor. [See Edit2 below!]

For example, if you have a `vector` or `std::string`, or whatever other class that needs destruction, in your baseclass, then you will leak the content of that class. In other words, you need to make 100% sure that the destructor of the baseclass is empty. I don't know of a programmatic way to determine that (beyond analysing the generated code, that is).

**Edit:**

Also beware of "changes in the future" - for example, adding a string or vector inside `Base` or changing the base class from `Base` to `SomethingInheritedFromBase` that has a destructor "with content" will ruin the "empty destructor" concept.

**Edit2:**

It should be noted that for the "destructor is empty", you have to have true empty destuctors in all derived clases too. There are classes that have no members that need destruction (interface classes typically have no data members, for example, so would not need destruction in themselves), so you could construct such a case, but again, we have to be VERY careful to avoid the destructor of a derived class adding a destructor into the class.

Comment: I don't understand your last two paragraphs. They seem to imply that an empty (`{}`) destructor will somehow prevent destructors of member variables from running, or that you can somehow prevent the derived destructor from calling the base destructor, but both statements are not correct.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I have clarified in such a way that I think it's more clear and correct.

Comment: Your "truly empty" destructor is the Trivial destructor that is already defined elsewhere and mentioned in my post. Actually it doesn't help at all. It neither prevents the direct calling of a non-virtual base destructor, nor does it avoid undefined behaviour. It does avoid a memory leak, but if we have undefined behaviour then that is the least of our worries.